# How to solve this "xpected primary-expression before ',' token"

Tags: programming

I'm new in this arduino world, and I'm having some trouble. I am programming something for a school assignment. The program gives an error, and my teacher also doesn't know how to solve it. Maybe someone can help me?

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>
#define speaker 

CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_3 = CapacitiveSensor(2,3);        
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_4 = CapacitiveSensor(2,4);         
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_5 = CapacitiveSensor(2,5);     
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_6 = CapacitiveSensor(2,6);     
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_7 = CapacitiveSensor(2,7);      
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_8 = CapacitiveSensor(2,8);         
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_9 = CapacitiveSensor(2,9);  
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_10 = CapacitiveSensor(2,10);     

int s1;
int s2;
int s3;
int s4;
int s5;
int s6;
int s7;
int s8;


void setup(){ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()                    
{

  s1 =  cs_2_3.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s2 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s3 =  cs_2_5.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s4 =  cs_2_6.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s5 =  cs_2_7.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s6 =  cs_2_8.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s7 =  cs_2_9.capacitiveSensor(3000);
  s8 =  cs_2_10.capacitiveSensor(3000);

  Serial.print("s1: ");
  Serial.println(s1);
  Serial.print("s2: ");
  Serial.println(s2);
  Serial.print("s3: ");
  Serial.println(s3);
  Serial.print("s4: ");
  Serial.println(s4);
  Serial.print("s5: ");
  Serial.println(s5);
  Serial.print("s6: ");
  Serial.println(s6);
  Serial.print("s7: ");
  Serial.println(s7);
  Serial.print("s8: ");
  Serial.println(s8);


  if (s1 > 500){  
    tone(speaker,131);   
   }
  else if (s2 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,147);   
   }
  else if (s3 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,165);
   }
  else if (s4 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,175);
   }
  else if (s5 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,196);
   }
  else if (s6 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,220);
   }
  else if (s7 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,247);
   }
  else if (s8 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,262);  
   }

  if (s1<=500  &&  s2<=500  &&  s3<=500 && s4<=500  &&  s5<=500  &&  s6<=500 &&  s7<=500 &&  s8<=500){
    noTone(speaker);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell the line where the error is given.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but the `else if` construct does not look very elegant, especially if tone s1 is supposed to have an equal priority to say s8.  Can you find another way of doing this part of the code?

Comment: Hint: What does "tone(speaker,131); " become if "#define speaker"?

Comment: This is the line where the error is given: else if (s8 > 500){ 
    tone(speaker,262);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
#define speaker
```

defines "speaker" as nothing, an empty string. Then:

```
tone(speaker,131);
```

is translated into

```
tone(,131);
```

which makes no sense. The compiler expected to find an expression before the comma.